# Renaming a class file no longer prompts to rename all occurrences

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, renaming, automated-refactoring

It used to be that when I renamed a class file (maybe also others) in VS2012, it prompted me to renamed everything, then did a nice refactor after renaming the class to the new file name. It suddenly stopped doing that. Does anyone know why it stopped, without me changing config or anything, or under what circumstances it doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio "rename" refactoring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065772/visual-studio-rename-refactoring)

Comment: I no longer receive this prompt, anyone know where the setting is so I can get this prompt once again?  And the answer is not in the thread from the comment above

Comment: I made sure the checkbox  "Prompt for symbolic renaming when renaming files" was checked under the Menu: Tools / Options expand Projects and Solutions .

Comment: thanks @DanO, that should probably be posted as the answer...

Answer (score -1):

Try changing class name, not file name. As 1 file can holds multiple classes.
(Don't know if this is true for VS, but it works like that in Java's Eclipse & IntelliJ.)

Comment: If I change the class name in its case only, I don't get the prompt to rename the file to match the class, and I have to do it as another, separate operation. I'm working with 245 classes.